# Getting Form Values returns undefined in IE only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pulling my hair out.  I have a form on my webpage and some javascript that is pulling the values from the form and I am taking various actions based on the input.

When troubleshooting, The value is being returned as undefined.

JS

```
var days = document.forms["meal-radio"].elements["days"].value;
```

HTML

```
        <form class= "meal-table" id="meal-radio" onsubmit="return false">
           <div class ="meal-plan-choice row" id="Meals4">
      ...................................................................
        <fieldset id="days">
              <div class="width40">
              <input type="radio" id="radio08" name="days" value="Five"/>
               <label for="radio08"><span class="radiospan"></span>5 Days</label>
            </div>


            <div class="width40">
           <input type="radio" id="radio09" name="days" value="Seven"/>
              <label for="radio09"><span class="radiospan"></span>7 Days</label>
            </div>

        </fieldset> <!-- end style fieldset-->
        ..............................................................
</div></form>
```

This is not working only in IE, works fine in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: I don't think [`HTMLFormElement.elements `](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) is supported in IE.

Comment: If you give the form the name meal-radio then you need to loop over the collection `document.forms["meal-radio"].elements["days"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being that you tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) in your question, I'm going to assume you're willing to accept jQuery answers.

You could use this, which works in all browsers:

```
var days = $("#days input[type='radio']:checked").val()
```

Comment: Youre the best, this works, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript:

```
// Get the form
var form = document.getElementById('meal-radio');

// Which is selected?
var currentSelected = form.querySelector('input[name="days"]:checked').value;

// Alert the value
alert( currentSelected ); // temp-alert
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/atr46c9r/1/

*Do note that in order to get the current selected radio it needs to actually have it's property set to :checked else there will/could be some issues in certain browsers.*